# Angular convert date

Tags: angular, electron

I have an input field called month.

```
  <span>
        Month: <br />
        <input id="typeahead-basic" type="text" class="form-control month" />
    </span>
```

What I want  to do is, if you type in 6 in the month field, it will automatically change to 06, if you type 2, it will change to 02. So everything from 1-9 should add a zero.
Would be nice if I could implement this into the component.ts class.
Thank you very much!

Edit:
So what I did was:
This in the component:

```
 checkMonth() {
    if (this.month < 1) {
        this.month = "01";
    } else if (this.month > 12) {
        this.month = 12;
    } else if (this.month < 10) {
        this.month = '0' + this.month;
    }
}
```

And this as the HTML code:

```
<input class="form-control hideSpinners" min=1 max=12 type="number" [(ngModel)]="month"
                (change)="checkMonth()"/>
```

Comment: use native javascript `'9'.padStart(2,0)`

Comment: How can I implement this in the component?

Comment: Bind to `(input)` event and add the padding. You can use other events for different behaviors. 

`(input)` triggers when a key is pressed.
`(change)` triggers when enter is pressed.
`(blur)` triggers when focus is moved.

Answer (score 1):

Impossible with simple HTML.

What you can do is call a function onChange when your value changes.

```
<span>
    Month: <br />
    <input id="typeahead-basic" type="text" class="form-control month" onchange="addZero(this)"/>
</span>
```

In your component script

```
addZero(input) {
    if(input.value > 0 && input.value < 10) input.value = `0${input.value}`;
}
```

Example : http://jsfiddle.net/nrjw56sv/ (Vanilla JS)
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-fr19pk (Angular)

Comment: Thank you very much, do I need to include the addZero function into what is called export class? Because I did that and it didnt work.

Comment: I don't know your architecture, but I suppose

Comment: I added the function and it tells me the function is unused, pretty weird.

Comment: Unused or undefined ?

Comment: It tells me it is unused

Comment: `Impossible with simple HTML.` ? Think again my friend !

Comment: What's wrong @trichetriche? I'm not sure to understand your comment

Comment: Look at my answer, particularly the second input, done all in HTML !

Comment: Yep that's a good way to do it. I think you missunderstood what I mean with `simple HTML`. I meant only HTML, with special attribute or something like that. In your example you use JS code to access to the input property.

Answer (score 1):

`slice` with a negative value will do the trick just fine :

```js
const input = document.querySelector('input[type="text"]#id');

input.addEventListener('blur', () => {
  input.value = input.value.length === 1 ? 
    `0${input.value}`.slice(-2) :
    input.value;
});
```

```html
<input id="id" type="text" placeholder="Enter a numeric value">
<input type="text" placeholder="Enter a numeric value (HTML only)" onblur="this.value = this.value.length === 1 ? ('0' + this.value).slice(-2) : this.value">
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the ngModel directive. So something like:

```
  <span>
        Month: <br />
        <input name="inputfield" #input [(ngModel)]="month" (input)="changeDate(month)" id="typeahead-basic" type="text" class="form-control month" />
    </span>
```

You'll need a public property in your component that matches the ngModel, so "month" in this case.

Then you'd just need to write a changeDate function that takes the ngModel value from the input field and adds the 0 to it, which is straight forward enough in vanilla javascript.